# ResetPassword function for CodeFirstMembership Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, code-first, reset-password

Does anyone know how to implement `ResetPassword` function for custom *Membership Provider* in **MVC3 app**?

Notice that I'm using [CodeFirstMembershipProvider](http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/). It seems to doesn't have such an implementation of `ResetPassword` function.